# How can I make a particle simulation into an animation?

Tags: animation, particles, blend4web

I made a rain simulation in Blend4Web using particles. I want to make this into an NLA or keyframe animation, so I can use it as an input for either the Play Animation or the Play Keyframe node in the Blend4Web logic node editor.

Do you guys have any suggestions on how can I do that?

Comment: You'd probably better ask this in the product's forum maybe more people there know the plugin and can help you better https://www.blend4web.com/en/forums/

Comment: I think the option "Allow NLA" in particles option may help you but I'm not 100% sure. It really is better to ask on forums - there's even a chance that somebody will even make you working example :) Also you can attach your .blend file there.